# How can I find matching values in two lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of numbers:

```
parasite genome   [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
host  genome      [1,1,0,0,1])
```

I am trying to find the chances of infection getting transferred from parasite to host. The transmission is directly proportional to the matching of 1's in the parasite and host genome. In this example case it is 3/10:

- 3 because positions of 1's matches in 3 places; and
- 10 is the length of the parasite genome.

I have written down the part of the program, but I am stuck in how to figure out the number of matches of 1's. Could someone please help me out?

```
host_genome_length = 10
parasite_genome_length = 5
maximum_infection_rate=1.0

def infection rate(host_genome, parasite_genome):
    if  host_genome_length > parasite_genome_length:
        return maximum_infection_rate *number of matches'of 1?(confused here)  / float (host_genome_length) 
    else:
        return maximum_infection_rate * number of matches'of 1?(confused here) / float (parasite_genome_length)    

print infection_rate([1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], [1,1,0,1,1])
```

Comment: Your question needs a better, more descriptive title.  It could also use a bit of grammar cleanup.

Comment: Do you just care about the number of matching from the beginning, or anywhere that the pattern matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) genome and host to check the elements at the same position:

```
>>> genome = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
>>> host = [1,1,0,0,1]

>>> print sum(1 for g, h in zip(genome, host) if g and h)
3
>>> # or
>>> print sum(g * h for g, h in zip(genome, host))
3
```